# How can I make the camera stop animating to updatedLocation, when user interacts?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

Imagine you are in a car right now and you are driving fast, so the camera follows the location and updates in seconds. But if you would like to scroll and see other places on the map it doesn't work, because you will get instantly back to the updated Location.

So that's why I am asking how to stop the camera from following the updated location when the user scrolls. And in addition, I would also like that the camera starts following the current location again when the user presses the myLocationButton.

Comment: read through the [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views)

Comment: follow this link and stop updating camera when you tap on map and start updating when you again tapped on my location https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this link and stop updating camera when you tap on map and start updating when you again tapped on my location

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/events

use this delegate method to reset the camera :-

```
public func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool {}
```

this can be used to stop camera if you are using marker

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        self.mapview.selectedMarker =  marker
 return true
}
```

Comment: when you tap in my location button again start updating camera and you can use this method to stop updating camera     public func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay)

Comment: you can use this  :-    declare a bool value and when you tap on map change the bool value true and and check update location if bool is false then update the camera. and when you tap on my location button change it to false and it will again start update camera location.